# Can I Add Specific Class to a paypal button code

Tags: css, class, button, paypal

I have a paypal button on a page like this...

```
<center><form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" 
target="_top"><input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_s-xclick" /> <input 
name="hosted_button_id" type="hidden" value="2222222222" /> <input 
class="responsive" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online!" 
height="125" name="submit" src="/images/orderbutton.png" type="image" 
width="475" /> <img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" 
alt="" width="1" height="1" border="0" /></form></center>
```

I am trying to get a popup to open on clicking the button... but the popup function requires a class and as you can see, all the buttons on a page have the same class "responsive"

What can I do to add a specific class for each button as each button leads to a different popup form so need to be different class for each button.

Im not a coder and just fumbling my way through. Any pointers examples appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want a PayPal button to pop up, perhaps a Smart button from https://www.paypal.com/buttons would meet your needs

Comment: Thanks but I changed the class. It was to popup a form as explained